# Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery at bootstrap.min.js:6, in an electron app

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angular, electron

I have built an electron app that uses Angular framework. Inside 'index.html' file I load bootstrap and jquery. But after electron app is built using electron-packager. I see this error.

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
```

From previous answers to this question I ensured jquery is loaded first and then the bootstrap. But still I see this error

For ref I have attached the index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Demo App</title>
      <base href="./">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
   </html>
```

But If I run the same as web app in browser, I don't see this error.
Note : As you see in the index.html, I am using CDN for jquery and bootstrap.

Any thoughts or suggestion would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the CDN library, I'd like to recommend using the jQuery npm package on Electron.

**npm install jquery**

```
<script>
  window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks tpikachu, I tried to load bootstrap and jquery locally instead of CDN but this as well didn't resolve this error

Comment: Have you installed jquery package?

Comment: @karansys to use my solution you need to enable the nodeIntegration while you are creating browserWIndow

Comment: By enabling the nodeIntegration you can use require() on the renderer. As this require is Node API not browser API.

Comment: Ok I will try that and let you know

Comment: Thats great @tpikachu , Its working. Any reason why bootstrap loads with cdn but not the jquery

Comment: Well, Bootstrap doesn't configure the browser property but just using

Comment: Not fully sure, why it is. Maybe related to security? haha.

Comment: Anyhow, in my experience. to define a new browser property manual config was the best choice especially for jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Add the bellow script in your html file:

```
<!-- Insert this line above script imports  -->
<script>
  if (typeof module === 'object') {    window.module = module; module = undefined;  }
  </script>
```

Then add scripts:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

then add the bellow:

```
<!-- Insert this line after script imports -->
<script>if (window.module) module = window.module;</script>
```